# Erro "nullpointerexception" ao trocar de activity

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema e gostaria que alguém pudesse solucionar para mim.
Sou novato no ramo de programação java e android, desenvolvi um projeto no qual eu testei e no modo debug rodou tudo certinho. Porém quando compilei e subi o projeto no google play e instalei no meu celular, consegui fazer o login, entretanto quando entra na próxima activity, o app da pau. Daí quando enviei o relatório o que recebi foi:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobilegenio.geniomobile/com.mobilegenio.geniocondominios.principalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mobilegenio.geniocondominios.principalActivity.onCreate(principalActivity.java:259)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5484)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
    ... 11 more
```

Segue meu código da activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.principal);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userId = intent.getStringExtra("userId");

        Button btnReport = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRp);
        Button btnNotas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNs);

        selectUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = '" + userId + "'";

        connect = CONN("xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
        if(QuerySQL(selectUser)) {
            lbNome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbNomeUser);
            lbAp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbAp);
            lbBloco = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbBloco);
            nomeCondominio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbNC);

            String nm = nome.toUpperCase();
            lbNome.setText(nm); //<----------------- AQUI DA PAU
            lbAp.setText(ap);
            lbBloco.setText(bloco);
            String selectCondominio = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM condominios WHERE Id = '" + condominio_Id + "'";
            QuerySQLCondominio(selectCondominio);
            nomeCondominio.setText(lbNomeCondominio);

            if(isSindico){
                btnReport.setText("REPORTES");
                btnNotas.setText("ESCREVER NOTA");
            }else{
                btnReport.setText("REPORTAR AO SÍNDICO");
                btnNotas.setText("NOTAS DO SÍNDICO");
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login ou Senha inválidos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Também o meu xml para que possa ficar um pouco mais claro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#197cd0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.07">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/logotopo"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/lbNC"
                android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

         android:layout_weight="0.07"

         android:background="#f2f3f6"

         android:baselineAligned="false"

         android:orientation="horizontal">



         <LinearLayout

             android:orientation="horizontal"

             android:layout_width="match_parent"

             android:layout_height="match_parent"

             android:weightSum="1">



             <TextView

                 android:layout_width="140dp"

                 android:layout_height="match_parent"

                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

                 android:text="Medium Text"

                 android:id="@+id/lbNomeUser"

                 android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

                 android:paddingTop="10dp"

                 android:paddingLeft="15dp"

                 android:textStyle="bold"

                 android:paddingRight="15dp"

                 android:layout_weight="0.65"

                 android:textSize="17dp" />



             <TextView

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

                 android:text="AP:"

                 android:id="@+id/textView3"

                 android:textStyle="bold"

                 android:paddingTop="20dp" />



             <TextView

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

                 android:text="100"

                 android:id="@+id/lbAp"

                 android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

                 android:paddingRight="15dp"

                 android:paddingTop="20dp" />



             <TextView

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

                 android:text="Bloco:"

                 android:id="@+id/textView"

                 android:textStyle="bold"/>



             <TextView

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

                 android:text="1"

                 android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

                 android:id="@+id/lbBloco" />



         </LinearLayout>

     </TableRow>



     <TableRow

         android:layout_width="match_parent"

         android:layout_height="match_parent"

         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

         android:layout_weight="0.5"

         android:background="@drawable/bg"

         android:gravity="top|left"

         android:paddingLeft="40dp"

         android:paddingRight="40dp"

         android:paddingTop="10dp"

         android:paddingBottom="20dp">



         <LinearLayout

             android:orientation="vertical"

             android:layout_width="match_parent"

             android:layout_height="match_parent">



             <LinearLayout

                 android:orientation="horizontal"

                 android:layout_width="match_parent"

                 android:layout_height="0dp"

                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                 android:layout_weight=".05">



                 <Button

                     android:layout_width="0dp"

                     android:layout_height="match_parent"

                     android:text=""

                     android:id="@+id/btnRp"

                     android:layout_weight=".5"

                     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

                     android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"

                     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/reportar"

                     android:drawablePadding="-10dp"

                     android:paddingTop="20dp"

                     android:textSize="10sp"

                     android:paddingLeft="9dp"

                     android:paddingRight="9dp"

                     android:onClick="reportarProblema"/>



                 <Button

                     android:layout_width="0dp"

                     android:layout_height="match_parent"

                     android:text="@string/btnAcordo"

                     android:id="@+id/btnAcordo"

                     android:layout_weight=".5"

                     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

                     android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"

                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/acordo"

                     android:drawablePadding="-10dp"

                     android:paddingTop="20dp"

                     android:textSize="10sp"

                     android:onClick="acordarVizinho"/>

             </LinearLayout>



             <LinearLayout

                 android:orientation="horizontal"

                 android:layout_width="match_parent"

                 android:layout_height="0dp"

                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                 android:layout_weight=".05">



                 <Button

                     android:layout_width="0dp"

                     android:layout_height="match_parent"

                     android:text="@string/btnServico"

                     android:id="@+id/btnServico"

                     android:layout_weight=".5"

                     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

                     android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"

                     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                     android:textSize="10sp"

                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/servicos"

                     android:drawablePadding="-10dp"

                     android:paddingTop="20dp"

                     android:onClick="servicos"/>



                 <Button

                     android:layout_width="0dp"

                     android:layout_height="match_parent"

                     android:text=""

                     android:id="@+id/btnNs"

                     android:layout_weight=".5"

                     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

                     android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"

                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                     android:textSize="10sp"

                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/notas"

                     android:drawablePadding="-10dp"

                     android:paddingTop="20dp"

                     android:onClick="notasSindico"/>

             </LinearLayout>



             <LinearLayout

                 android:orientation="horizontal"

                 android:layout_width="match_parent"

                 android:layout_height="0dp"

                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                 android:layout_weight=".05">



                 <Button

                     android:layout_width="0dp"

                     android:layout_height="match_parent"

                     android:text="@string/btnAgenda"

                     android:id="@+id/btnAgenda"

                     android:layout_weight=".5"

                     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

                     android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"

                     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                     android:textSize="10sp"

                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/agenda"

                     android:drawablePadding="-10dp"

                     android:paddingTop="20dp"

                     android:onClick="agendamentos"/>



                 <Button

                     android:layout_width="0dp"

                     android:layout_height="match_parent"

                     android:text="@string/btnCamera"

                     android:id="@+id/btnCam"

                     android:layout_weight=".5"

                     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

                     android:textColor="@color/corTextoONAzul"

                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                     android:textSize="10sp"

                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/tirarfoto"

                     android:drawablePadding="-10dp"

                     android:paddingTop="20dp"

                     android:onClick="fotos"/>

             </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>

     </TableRow>



     <TableRow

         android:layout_width="match_parent"

         android:layout_height="72dp"

         android:background="#485d8a"></TableRow>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Lembrando que a linha que ta dando pau está o código: `lbNome.setText(nm);`.

Desconfiei que pudesse ser algo com o banco de dados ou como eu estava criando uma conexão nova a cada activity, entretanto não pode ser banco porque na main ele consegue acessar o banco, fazer o select e verificar se existe o usuário. Suspeitando que fosse a conexao, eu criei uma classe de conexão onde crio apenas uma conexão no momento da autenticação do usuário.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

A variável nm é nula, por isso o erro.

Provavelmente o problema está na linha abaixo:

> String nm = nome.toUpperCase();

Verifica a variável nome e veja se existe algum valor nela antes de realizar o "toUpperCase".

Comment: então, essa variável recebe um dado do banco de dados, mas já verifiquei e está retornando normalmente.

Comment: @judeugabriel Ok. Verifique se o id R.id.lbNomeUser consta realmente no seu arquivo de layout principal.

Comment: consta, porém tive problemas em reconhecer os buttons, tive que adicionar um item no manifest para que fosse possivel, por precaução ja inseri os itens das textviews no manifest também mas não obtive sucesso!

Comment: Porque é que rodando o debug do meu projeto ele roda certinho e na versão release da esse problema?